# C# - Как выразить данное выражение в код

Tags: c#

Как можно выразить данное выражание в код?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
double e = Math.Exp(x + 1) * Math.Exp(x + 1);
Math.Round(0.33 * e, 10);
```

моя строчка кода не работает

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется тут скорее так степень нужно считать:

```
double e = Math.Exp((x + 1) * (x + 1));
```

Comment: точно, совсем не заметил этого, спасибо

Comment: @foder. чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.